# SQL: JOIN tables with the result having unique values on one of the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join two tables but to specify that the result should have unique values on one of the columns.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ded/4

Instead of

```
URLID DOMAINID
13    5
9     3
10    3
11    4
12    4
6     2
7     2
8     2
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
```

I would like to get:

```
URLID DOMAINID
13    5
9     3
11    4
6     2
1     1
```

Is it possible doing it and by that creating a **faster** query?

Comment: Having multiple `DOMAINID`, you want the smallest `URLID` for that `DOMAINID`?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ded/9 is it what you want?

Comment: @FrancisP - no, just one `URLID` no matter which

Comment: Then, a simple `GROUP BY` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will not be faster, because you have to remove the duplicates.  Here is a MySQL way:

```
select urlID, domainID
from (<your query>) as t
group by domainID
```

This uses a MySQL mis(feature) called hidden columns.  In most databases, you would use:

```
select min(urlID), domainID
from (<your query>) as t
group by domainID
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I just applied an aggregate to the `urlid` and added a `group by`:

```
SELECT min(urlid) urlid, domain_stack.domainid 
FROM  domain_stack
INNER JOIN url_stack
  ON url_stack.domainid = domain_stack.domainid
group by domain_stack.domainid 
order by domain_stack.domainid desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ded/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT urlid,domain_stack.domainid
FROM  domain_stack
INNER JOIN url_stack
ON url_stack.domainid = domain_stack.domainid
GROUP BY domainid
```